# Fetching data from user selection with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

So I am pretty new to React Hooks and can't seem to figure this out.  What I am trying to do is have the user select an item from the dropdown menu and fetch data every time a user selects a new item. The 'selectedState' variable is updating when a user chooses an item from the dropdown menu, but my useEffect function has to fetch data twice before getting the correct data for the current 'selectedState'. I have thought about separating the dropdown into its own component and passing the data to another component to fetch the data, but I don't know if that would actually fix the problem.

here is my code:

```
    const initialState = () => {
        return {
            loading: true,
            post: '',
            error: ''
        }
    }

function reducer(state, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'fetch_success':
                return {
                    loading: false,
                    post: action.payload,
                    error: ''
                }
            case 'fetch_error':
                return {
                    loading: false,
                    post: {},
                    error: 'Something went wrong'
                }
            default:
                return state
        }
    }

    export default () => {
        const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
        const [selectedState, getSelectedState] = useState('');
        const dropDownList = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'American Samoa', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'District of Columbia', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Guam', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Minor Outlying Islands', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Northern Mariana Islands', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Puerto Rico', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'U.S. Virgin Islands', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming']


        const dropDown =
            <select
                id="state-dropdown"
                onChange={e => getSelectedState(e.target.value)}
                value={selectedState}
                disabled={!dropDownList.length}>
                <option>Choose State</option>
                {dropDownList.map((item) => <option key={item} value={item}>{item}</option>)}
            </select >


        useEffect(() => {
            async function fetchData() {
                const response = await fetch((`https://covid-19-statistics.p.rapidapi.com/reports?&iso=USA&region_name=US&date=2020-04-16&q=US%20${selectedState}`), {
                    "method": "GET",
                    "headers": {
                        "x-rapidapi-host": "covid-19-statistics.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "x-rapidapi-key": "8eb0a7c674msh30916dd1116d55cp1700f5jsn651eb7015384"
                    }
                });
                dispatch({ type: 'fetch_success', payload: response.json() });
            }
            fetchData();
        }, [selectedState, dispatch]);

        {console.log(state)}


        return (
            <div>
                <CardHeader>- State -</CardHeader>
                <Card>
                    <label>
                        {dropDown}
                    </label>
                </Card>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: `useEffect` is called once when your component is mounted, which means that there will be a fetch with an empty `selectedState`, is that OK?

Comment: No, that is what I am trying to remedy.  I presume it's because the state is being updated every time i "getSelectedState" as well as when the useEffect function runs, but I don't know how to get around that behavior with hooks.